# Windows Store - Validate receipts with Java

Tags: java, windows-store, xml-signature

Microsoft provides a C# implementation but I am having problems porting it to Java.

C# implementation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj649137.aspx

Certificate (downloaded from Microsoft):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Sample receipt (provided by Microsoft):

```
<Receipt Version="1.0" ReceiptDate="2012-08-30T23:10:05Z" CertificateId="b809e47cd0110a4db043b3f73e83acd917fe1336" ReceiptDeviceId="4e362949-acc3-fe3a-e71b-89893eb4f528">
    <AppReceipt Id="8ffa256d-eca8-712a-7cf8-cbf5522df24b" AppId="55428GreenlakeApps.CurrentAppSimulatorEventTest_z7q3q7z11crfr" PurchaseDate="2012-06-04T23:07:24Z" LicenseType="Full" />
    <ProductReceipt Id="6bbf4366-6fb2-8be8-7947-92fd5f683530" ProductId="Product1" PurchaseDate="2012-08-30T23:08:52Z" ExpirationDate="2012-09-02T23:08:49Z" ProductType="Durable" AppId="55428GreenlakeApps.CurrentAppSimulatorEventTest_z7q3q7z11crfr" />
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>cdiU06eD8X/w1aGCHeaGCG9w/kWZ8I099rw4mmPpvdU=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>SjRIxS/2r2P6ZdgaR9bwUSa6ZItYYFpKLJZrnAa3zkMylbiWjh9oZGGng2p6/gtBHC2dSTZlLbqnysJjl7mQp/A3wKaIkzjyRXv3kxoVaSV0pkqiPt04cIfFTP0JZkE5QD/vYxiWjeyGp1dThEM2RV811sRWvmEs/hHhVxb32e8xCLtpALYx3a9lW51zRJJN0eNdPAvNoiCJlnogAoTToUQLHs72I1dECnSbeNPXiG7klpy5boKKMCZfnVXXkneWvVFtAA1h2sB7ll40LEHO4oYN6VzD+uKd76QOgGmsu9iGVyRvvmMtahvtL1/pxoxsTRedhKq6zrzCfT8qfh3C1w==</SignatureValue>
    </Signature>
</Receipt>
```

Java implementation:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream("/XMLFile1.xml"));

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
    throw new Exception("Cannot find Signature element");
}

String base64CertString = "MIIDyTCCArG...   // Copied from certificate without new lines and -- BEGIN .. END stuff ...
byte  data[] = Base64.decodeBase64(base64CertString);
CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) f.generateCertificate( new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

certificate.checkValidity(); // Validates OK!

PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();          

// document containing the XMLSignature
DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(pk, nl.item(0));

String providerName = System.getProperty("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());

XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
boolean valid = signature.validate(valContext);

// Check core validation status
if (valid == false) {
    System.out.println("Signature failed core validation");
    boolean sv = signature.getSignatureValue().validate(valContext);
    System.out.println("signature validation status: " + sv);
    // check the validation status of each Reference
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Iterator i = signature.getSignedInfo().getReferences().iterator();
    for (int j=0; i.hasNext(); j++) {
        boolean refValid = ((Reference) i.next()).validate(valContext);
        System.out.println("ref["+j+"] validity status: " + refValid);
    }            
} else {
    System.out.println("Signature passed core validation");
}
```

The validation fails both in signature validation and reference validation. Why?

Answer (score 2):

if you use java to check the receipt, you should remove white space between character ">" and "<", then you will success

Answer (score 0):

I had it working by trimming each line of xml using this code:

```
private static String trim(String input) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line.trim());
        }

        return result.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```